# Background image Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Hi this is my first question on Stack Owerflow. I am trying to solve a challenge on Frontend Mentor. 
I have made a container with 2 columns, and I want to place a SVG background image on the left col. 
I have tried to insert the SVG in the HTML file, and it worked, but when I use CSS nothing happens. 
This is the code:

'''

```
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">  
     <div class="row"> 
       <div class="col-7 left">
        <h1> We're coming soon</h1>

      Hello fellow shoppers! We're currently building our new fashion store.
      Add your email below to stay up-to-date with announcements and our launch deals.

      Email Address
       </div>

     <!-- Right side -->
    <div class="col-5">
      <img src="images/hero-desktop.jpg">
    </div>
    </div>
   </div>
</body>




.left{
    background-image: url('images/bg-pattern-desktop.svg');
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: auto;
}
```

'''

Can anyone help me.

Feel free to comment on my frist question.

Thanks 
Karsten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### It's Working. Try this in bootstrap version 4.4.1

```css
.left {
  background: url('images/bg-pattern-desktop.svg') no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
   height: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">  
     <div class="row"> 
       <div class="col-7 left">
        <h1> We're coming soon</h1>

      Hello fellow shoppers! We're currently building our new fashion store.
      Add your email below to stay up-to-date with announcements and our launch deals.

      Email Address
       </div>

     <!-- Right side -->
    <div class="col-5">
      <img src="images/hero-desktop.jpg">
    </div>
    </div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

your css should be in `<style>` tag if you are adding that in `.html` page

if you are adding that css in seperate css file then make sure image path is proper or check your console you must be getting 404 file not found error

```
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">  
     <div class="row"> 
       <div class="col-7 left">
        <h1> We're coming soon</h1>

      Hello fellow shoppers! We're currently building our new fashion store.
      Add your email below to stay up-to-date with announcements and our launch deals.

      Email Address
       </div>

     <!-- Right side -->
    <div class="col-5">
      <img src="images/hero-desktop.jpg">
    </div>
    </div>
   </div>
</body>



<style>
.left{
    background-image: url('images/bg-pattern-desktop.svg');
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: auto;
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

All other work is great just specify your exact path:

```
{
  background-image: url("C:\Desktop\images\bg-pattern-desktop.svg");
}
```

Just get where the image is located i.e its directory for the root disk and add with the image name

Like:
Directory root + image name
c:\Users(username)\Desktop\ + picture.jpg.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code,To Background image Bootstrap

```
<body class="left">
  <div class="container-fluid">  
     <div class="row"> 
       <div class="col-7">
        <h1> We're coming soon</h1>

      Hello fellow shoppers! We're currently building our new fashion store.
      Add your email below to stay up-to-date with announcements and our launch deals.

      Email Address
       </div>

     <!-- Right side -->
    <div class="col-5">
      <img src="images/hero-desktop.jpg">
    </div>
    </div>
   </div>
</body>

.left{
    background-image: url("https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Horizontal/Nature/full page/img(20).jpg");
    height:100%;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: auto;
}
body{
height:100%;}
```

I hope this code will be usefull for you.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bootstrap Grid, Example as below to display image in background in left column and text in another column in the same row.

```css
.container {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20x;
  display: flex;
}

.left {
  background-image: url("https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/sunset-over-ocean-260nw-66975196.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 200px;
  width: auto;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Radha Yadav Web Developer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-grid.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="BackgroundImage.css" /> 
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 left">
          <h1>We're coming soon</h1>

          Hello fellow shoppers! We're currently building our new fashion store.
          Add your email below to stay up-to-date with announcements and our
          launch deals. Email Address
        </div>

        <!-- Right side -->
        <div class="col-md-6 right">
            <h1>We're coming soon</h1>

            Hello fellow shoppers! We're currently building our new fashion store.
            Add your email below to stay up-to-date with announcements and our
            launch deals. Email Address
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```